# my first simple cgi bash file

Tags: linux, bash, cgi

I use my internet browser to display images/graphs I created with `gnuplot`. So for each picture I have a `plot.gp` file that contains `gnuplot` commands. My final goal is to open an editor with the file `plot.gp` when I click on the picture.

The only way I found to achieve this is to use `cgi` to run a bash scripts. But I'm not able to make an "hello word" code work... So here is what I did :

- I installed on linux the packaged cgi-mapserver
- I saved in the file `hello.bash` in `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/` and gave it the correct permission (`chmod 755 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/hello.bash)`.

But when I do `firefox /usr/lib/cgi-bin/hello.bash` my browser display the whole file instead of only "hello world!"

My file `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/hello.bash` :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html><head><title>Welcome</title></head>"
echo "<body>"
echo "Hello world"
echo "</body></html>"
```

I'm sure I forget something very basic... but I can't figure what it is :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use your browser's file associations to use your editor for downloaded .gp files.
It is a web server, not a browser, who uses cgi-scripts.

Comment: okay... so it means that I should set the parameters of my browser to run a script when I click on a hyperlink to a .gp file?

Comment: Yes. Or just to run an editor directly without scripts. To do it with cgi you should set up a web server to run a script on accessing some url and embed some in-browser editor (flash-based or something) in it's output.

Answer (score 0):

Browser cannot run the shell script and show it's output. You can store shell script's output in a temp HTML file and open it like thisL

```
bash /usr/lib/cgi-bin/hello.bash > /tmp/hello.html
```

And then open it in firefox:

```
firefox file:///tmp/hello.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is in reply to a very old help request. But makbe it will help someone.

Provided that your server supports cgi and you moved the hello.bash script to the directory of cgi-bin. And then changed permissions to at least 644 and and owner ship of root:users. It will run as posted.

Doing this in LAMPP, from the browser I enter http://localhost/cgi-bin/hello.bash and I can see "Hello world"